# MongoDB Trigger Function // TypeError: Cannot access member 'id' of undefined

Tags: mongodb, function, authentication, realm, datatrigger

I'm trying to crate a file when a User will the first time be authenticated. I use the down below function. Somehow I am getting the following error: "TypeError: Cannot access member 'id' of undefined". I don't know why I can't access the user.id.

```
 exports = function(authEvent){
      const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
      const users = mongodb.db('data').collection('User');
      const { user } = authEvent
      const newObjcId = new BSON.ObjectId()
      
      const newUser = {
        _id: newObjcId,
        realm_id: user.id
      };

  
  return users.updateOne({_id: newObjcId}, newUser, {upsert: true});
};
```

Comment: `user` appears to be undefined or incorrectly defined according to the error. I would take a look at this line `const { user } = authEvent`

Comment: test with `realm_id: user` maybe even add in `event: authEvent`.  Then you will be able to see the exact value of both.

Comment: If I test it with realm_id: user the Collections shows that this is a User Object with an id, a type and more.